# Не отображаются иконки в меню

Tags: menu, android, java, icon

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    menu.add(Menu.NONE, IDM_OPEN, Menu.NONE, "Open")
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_upload_you_tube);
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, IDM_SAVE, Menu.NONE, "Save")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, IDM_EDIT, Menu.NONE, "Edit")
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_edit);
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, IDM_HELP, Menu.NONE, "Help")
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_help);
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, IDM_EXIT, Menu.NONE, "Exit")
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel);

    return (super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
}
```

Comment: А в xml что?

Comment: В XML все работает, спасибо